# how to get target values from inner json arrays

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

How can I select target values that correspond to the names selected from drop a down menu. [I have a dataset](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/heenaI/cbbc5c5f49994f174376/raw/55c672bbca7991442f1209cfbbb6ded45d5e8c8e/data.json) in hierarchical structure that has the following structure:

World has => children: continents have => Children Countries

Now I want to get the values of individual country when it's name is selected from dropdown.

When I try my code it returns error

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of null**

Which I suppose means that I cannot get to the values I need. 
 Js fiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/9tnmwdyv/3/**

My code:

```
function checkIt(error, root){
     if (error) throw error;

    var partition = d3.layout.partition()
                  .value(function(d) { return d.Total; });

        var dropDown = d3.select("#dropdown_container")
                   .append("select")
                   .attr("class", "selection")
                    .attr("name", "country-list");

    var options = dropDown.selectAll("option")
                  .data(partition.nodes(root))
                  .enter()
                  .append("option");
         options.text(function (d) { var dropdownValues = d.name.replace(/[_-]/g, " ");
                                     return dropdownValues.replace(/[_-]/g, " ") })
       .attr("value", function (d) { var dropdownValues = d.name;
                                     return dropdownValues});

    function changePie() {

    //get the data value and index from the event
    var selectedValue = d3.event.target;
    var selectedIndex = d3.event.target.selectedIndex;

    //alert("You selected the option at index " + selectedIndex + ", with value attribute "+ selectedValue);

    var selectedDOMElement =
        d3.event.target.children[selectedIndex];
    var selection = d3.select(selectedDOMElement);

//Output selected country with all its values
    var uniqueData = data[selectedIndex];
        console.log(uniqueData)
    }
changePie();
};

d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/heenaI/cbbc5c5f49994f174376/raw/55c672bbca7991442f1209cfbbb6ded45d5e8c8e/data.json", checkIt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking changePie yourself, it should be invoked as an event callback. d3.events.target is null because "d3.events" does not have property named "target", it's not the event object passed to callback. Also you can access the target element using "this" inside the callback function, it's plain DOM element. If you need to invoke d3 methods on it, just wrap it with d3 as **d3.select(this)**

Below is the code showing an event callback

```
d3.select(".selection").on("change", function changePie() {
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

Working Jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9tnmwdyv/6/

Edited*

If you want to access the corresponding data, you can just save the partitioned array in a variable and access it.

```
var nodeArr = partition.nodes(root);
d3.select(".selection").on("change", function changePie() {
    var value = this.value;
    var index = this.selectedIndex;
    var dataObj = nodeArr[index];
    console.log(this.value + " : " + dataObj.Total + " in " + (dataObj.parent && dataObj.parent.name));
});
```

Check the Jsfiddle link below:

http://jsfiddle.net/9tnmwdyv/10/

Comment: You are right but console.log(this-value) gives the name of the country whereas what I want is the data from the dataset corresponding to the selected country

Comment: Updated my answer to get the data for selected option.